# Dropdownlist input within a Kendo grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Quick explanation of my issue: I have an editable Kendo grid, and one of the columns is a dropdownlist, defined as such:

```
$('<input required data-text-field="fullName" data-value-field="approverGuid" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendoDropDownList({
        index: 0,
        dataTextField: "fullName",
        dataValueField: "approverGuid",
        autoBind: false,
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '/requisitions/ajax/getreqapprovers?account=' + accountNum
                }
            },
        },
        value: options.field
    });
```

My problem is that on initial grid load, the column is just a regular text element, populated with the approverGuid field, when I want to display the fullName field. As soon as I click in the grid, the dropdownlist is created, and we now see the correct fullName that corresponds with the approverGuid we saw previously. I can select any name in my dropdown, update, and it correctly writes the approverGuid to my DB but it also reverts back to the approverGuid in my grid, since the dropdownlist element is gone.

Any suggestions on how to display the name initially, without losing the Guid value which is needed to update my DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I Understand you correctly you need to show the "fullName" instead of "approverGuid"

If So I Hope You have a  model Define in your dataSource . if not Look in to [Kendo API MODEL](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.model)

eg:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  schema: {
    model: {
       id: "ID",
       fields: {
         ID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
         approverGuid: { type: "number", validation: { required: true } },
         fullName: { type: "string", validation: { required: true } }
    }
  }
```

once you have a model you will have access to a dataitem , with the use of this you can define a template for the grid column

eg:

```
columns: [
        {
          field: "approverGuid",
          title: "approverGuid",
          template: function (dataItem) {
              var html = '<span class="">' + kendo.htmlEncode(dataItem.fullName) + '</span>';
                    return html;
          },
          editor: function (container, options) {
            $('<input required data-text-field="fullName" data-value-field="approverGuid" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
             .kendoDropDownList({
                index: 0,
             dataTextField: "fullName",
             dataValueField: "approverGuid",
             autoBind: false,
             dataSource: {
               transport: {
                  read: {
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '/requisitions/ajax/getreqapprovers?account=' + accountNum
                }
             },
          },
          value: options.field
            });
           }
        }]
```

So now The Template will Show the fullname and Once you are in edit mode you will the the dropdown list . Hope this helps

Comment: EXACTLY, what I needed, clearly explained with code. Serious props, thanks!

Comment: Interesting anomaly occurring after update, however; I can select a new value from the dropdown, click update on the row (using Kendo Grid inline editing), and the new approverGuid gets written to the DB, but the old name value remains in the grid. If I click back in the dropdown it will display the correct corresponding name. I can also refresh the entire grid, and it will display the correct name. I don't want to force a refresh, however, there must be a way to get the newly selected name to show up on the grid without a refresh.

Comment: the problem is that your dataSource Update url is expecting the return result and if you have specify to expect a Json and if you return a string or nothing this will occur . eg: "Update: {dataType: 'json' " , it is best to return back the updated item as a Json result. I think this is the issue if not let me know.